# Как в php добавить водный знак при скачивании изображения?

Tags: php

Собственно вопрос из шапки.

1) Возможно ли наложить водный на скачиваемое изображение (Пкм -> сохранить как). Если да то подскажите как ?

2) Как наложить водный знак на изображение если оно находится на другом сайте. То бишь на своем сайте (допустим localhost.com) оно без водного знака , а вот если нажать скопировать изображение либо скопировать ссылку на изображение и вставить (допустим в сообщение на vk.com) то на этом изображении появится водный знак.

Вы просто подскажите как мне это реализовать если это возможно, а код я смогу написать.

Comment: Watermark накладывается на изображение и становится его частью, то есть 1+1=1. Если вы хотите хранить у себя одно, а на левый сайт отдавать другое, то должна быть специальная ссылка, которая будет получать запрашиваемый файл, накладывать ватермарк и отдавать цельное изображение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1-й пункт, к сожалению - никак. Есть вариант только запретить пкм на сайте через JS но он не обеспечит запрет получения картинки

2. Такой вариант возможен например если картинку подгружать не напрямую, а через скрипт, например

   `<img src="http://localhost.com/image.php?name=myimage">`

в корне нужно создать файл image.php с примерно следующим содержимым

```
<?php
#файл image.php
$host $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$my_site = 'localhost.com';
if($host == $my_site){
//Запрос с нашего хоста
 //тут ищем изображение с ID которое приходит с $_GET['name']
echo $image;
}else{
//Запрос с другого хоста
//тут ищем изображение и накладываем на него watermark
echo $image;
}
?>
```